# close tab/redirect if cancel is pressed?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a site that requires a password to get onto it but once the password prompt is up, it's too difficult (not user-friendly) to go back. The purpose of the password is to keep the user from seeing the page and the page source.
Here's what I have thus far:

```
        do{
            $('html').hide();  //hiding html with jQuery
            var pass = "password";  //setting password
            var selection = prompt("Enter password", "");  //prompting for password
            if(selection == "cancel"){
                window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
            };  //trying (unsuccesfully) to make the page redirect if user answers "cancel"
        } while(selection!=pass);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

`If the user clicks the Cancel button, this function returns null.`

So,

```
do{
  $('html').hide();
  var pass = "password";
  var selection = prompt("Enter password", "");
  if(selection === null) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
    break;
  };
} while(selection !== pass);
```

You need the break statement, because the browser will not redirect if there is still code running, like the while loop here.

Comment: I need it to redirect when the cancel button is pressed, which isn't happening in my tests